# Many request to parse at once

Tags: javascript, swift, parse-platform

I have a list of request to make to Parse.com using the swif API for tasks acumulated once the application was offine. Some tests show that if I dowload it all at once the overall time is slow that is I use multiple requests. However I couldn't figureout how can I request many "random" objectId's from Pase.com (I have a list of course, by random I mean out of order and not a fix number)

At the moment I am using a loop and calling many:

```
 let pred = NSPredicate(format: "newDataID = %@, dataID[i])
 query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (result:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?)
```

I was thinking in auto generate the string for the predicate but it can get very long what I image would make the query very slow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under any circumstances, initiating many requests in a tight loop is ill-advised.  Instead, send the dataID array to a cloud function.  Also, if its really an array of object ids, then find is the wrong method, use get() instead...

```
var _ = require('underscore');  // underscore includes many handy functions, including map and toArray

Parse.Cloud.define("getManyObjectsById", function(request, response) {
    var dataID = request.params.dataID;
    var promises = _.map(dataID, function(anID) {
        var query = new Parse.Query("MyCustomClassName");
        return query.get(anID);
    });
    Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function() {
        response.success(_.toArray(arguments));
    }, function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    });
});
```

Call it...

```
PFCloud.callFunctionInBackground("getManyObjectsById", withParameters: dataID) {
  (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
      // objects should be an array of objects corresponding to the ids
}
```

Comment: Thanks I have been pulling my hair out to understand how to use the javascript code you post above using using the parse code, how do I upload it to parse? Thanks in advance

Comment: See the section of docs on cloud code.  (see the links in the Getting Started section https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#cloud-code).  You'll get a little command line tool that will let you deploy the JS function to your app.

Comment: I had problems with the deployment part in the weekend I think I was just burnout today was so easy! In what file/directory should I add this code? Thanks!